# What things require performing ghusl?

Tags: ghusl

After I did ghusl and I wiped my butt I found some poo. Is my ghusl valid please answer me fast I'm worried. Answer simple please

Comment: This seems to mean you didn't wash your butt. Defecating itself is not invalidating ghusl.

Answer (score 3):

Note that ghusl doesn't become invalid by what invalidates wudu'.

**The things which require performing ghusl**

It only invalidates by what makes it necessary such as:

- semen emission due to lust and desire.
- nocturnal emission.
- intercourse (with or without semen emission)
- end of menses or childbed bleeding
- death (this is the only case where somebody else must perform ghusl for you).
- conversion (accepting Islam according the MalikI's and Hanbali's)
- ghusl for jmu'ah according the Hanbali's.

Further more the majority of scholars consider niyyah as essential and therefore performing ghusl without it would invalidate from their perspective.

So as long as none of these happened while performing ghusl your ghusl is valid. Even if this may show that you didn't do it well.

Comment: Basically I did stanja before ghusl and I did wipe my butt when it was the part where you need to clean your privet part while ghusl.

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: @Uwni what don't you understand? When I say your ghusl is valid?

Comment: Is it and I have another problem will you answer it for me

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/62865/39731