# Sperm after wet dream and having doubt

Tags: taharah, najis, waswasa

Salam, after having a wet dream I was checking my blanket covers for traces of wet dream and I couldn’t find anything or any smell. I removed the cover for the blanket to put my mind at ease so I could sleep. My question is if no traces can be found is it deemed as clean? Please I need a answer so I can put my mind at ease jazakallah

Comment: The blanket has to have stains to be islamically unclean. If semen dries up, it normally leaves a hard surface on the blanket. If this can't be found, the blanket is clean

Answer (score 3):

The ejaculation is among the reasons for the obligation to perform ghusl.
Having a wet dream is rather a reason for expecting an ejaculation (in case it was found we'd be talking about a nocturnal emission).
But **only if the traces of this ejaculation are found ghusl becomes obligatory**.

See also:
[What things require performing ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/what-things-require-performing-ghusl/62864#62864)

Comment: Jazakallah khair for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu

It is not obligatory for you to perform ghusul since there's no trace's if you are sure that you are not lying to yourself, but you can still do it since there's no Haram or sin cause when doing it, is part of the sunna of your beloved prophet

Also there's is an Hadith which gives clear image on this as the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) answered the woman who asked him: "Does a woman have to perform Ghusl when she has a wet dream?, and he replied: "Yes, if she sees any water (white) discharges." [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

This may also apply to man

An Allah knows the best

Comment: Jazakallah khair. But what about the bed sheets there’s no trace so is it deemed pure?

Comment: @Usman The best way to take your self out of confusion is to just take the bath but if you are not able to do it is still pure

Comment: Yeah I changed the sheet and performed ghusl to be safe

Comment: That was perfect, you can know accept the answer

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question as it is about the blanket not janabat