# Does colored dripping need wudu or Ghusl?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

I have been going mad over this issue and about what to do. Sometimes when standing up from the commode after cleaning Feces there are light brow water drops on the seat which is of course dropping from my rear when standing up.

Just to be clear I clean with around 1/2 liters of water but still those drops fall off.

Does it mean my body is not clean anymore and I need more make wudu or Ghusl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle is that the garment and body remains pure (taahir) until and unless you are certain that impurity has got onto it. If you are certain that drops have fallen, then you must wash the area which is touched by impurity and do wudoo, and wash off whatever gets onto your clothes of that. But if there is any uncertainty(might be/may be) about that, then you do not have to do anything, and you should ignore the doubts and uncertainty.

> Shaykh al-Islam (may Allah have mercy on him) was asked: What if a
> person does wudoo’ and starts to pray, then feels a drip during his
> prayer: is his prayer invalidated or not?
>
> He replied: Merely feeling something does not invalidate wudoo’ and it
> is not permissible for him to stop an obligatory prayer because of a
> mere doubt. But if he becomes certain that urine has escaped to the
> exterior of the private part, then his wudoo’ is invalidated and he
> has to clean himself with water (istinja’), unless he suffers from
> urinary incontinence, in which case that does not invalidate his
> prayer if he has done what he is enjoined to do.
>
> End quote. Majmoo‘ al-Fataawa, 21/219-220

Answer (score 1):

The matters which require wudu are listed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103) and the matters which require ghusl are listed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/). What you have mentioned requires neither but rather maybe requires proper istinja i.e. use water and your hand to scrub your backside clean. Of-course ghusl (bath) will also work but is not required, you are only required to remove the filth itself.

Comment: There is fear that the colored dripping might have fallen inside of clothes while standing, do one need to change clothes or just do istinja again? Just happened this morning while I was gonna do Wudu and it happened so I decided to find out more before I pray