# Jannabat bath and the procedure to be a sincere Muslim

Tags: ghusl

My question goes that what is the difference between ghsul jannabat bath and ghusul to become a Muslim totally???and what are the procedure to become a Muslim.
If I can see someone who can specify the two for me I will be greatful.

Comment: Ghusl in Islam is a term used for a procedure of purification, the reasons for it's necessity maybe different, but not the procedure itself

Comment: Also see [What things require performing ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/)