# For a Girl, Is ghusal fard or not after intimate scene?

Tags: halal-haram, ghusl

I want to ask a question that If a girl saw and intimate video and gets wet or a little release even if she didn't touch, Is she has to perform ghusal for Namaz or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What things require performing ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/what-things-require-performing-ghusl)

Answer (score -1):

> The Causes of Ghusl Janabat There are two causes of janabat:
>
> Discharge of semen. It does not make any difference whether this
> discharge is while awake or in a wet-dream, slight or profuse,
> intentionally or otherwise, in lawful way or unlawful (e.g.,
> masturbation). In all these cases ghusl janabat becomes obligatory
> (wajib). If a liquid comes out from a man and he does not know whether
> or not it is semen, then he should look for the following three signs:
> (1) emission with passion; (2) spurting discharge; (3) feeling relaxed
> after the discharge. If these signs are found together on him, then he
> should consider the liquid as semen, otherwise not. If a secretion is
> discharged from a woman, then it is precautionary wajib for her to do
> ghusl janabat provided it came with sexual passion and she felt
> relaxed after it. But if the secretion comes without the sexual
> passion or without the feeling of relaxation after the discharge, then
> it is not najis and therefore ghusl is not wajib upon her.
>
> Sexual Intercourse. It does not make any difference whether the
> intercourse was lawful or unlawful, and with or without discharge of
> semen. In Islamic laws, sexual intercourse is defined as the
> penetration of the glans into the vagina or anus of the woman. That
> is, for ghusl janabat to become wajib it is not necessary that full
> penetration or discharge of semen should take place. In case of sexual
> intercourse, ghusl janabat becomes wajib on both the man and the
> woman.

[Reference: Islamic Marriage Handbook](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-marriage-handbook-sayyid-athar-husayn-sh-rizvi/major-ablution-ghusl-janabat)